# Маршаллинг FILE* в C#

Tags: c#, c

Мне надо использовать некую структуру. Вот код этой структуры:

```
typedef struct
{
    /*код*/
    FILE* hndlFileDownload;
    /*код*/
} Struct1;
```

Так вот, как обозначить `hndlFileDownload`? `IntPtr`?

По [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212713/marshaling-from-c-sharp-to-c) ответу я не могу все сделать, поскольку не могу изменить dll-ку.

Comment: А зачем менять dll? Не достаточно использовать то, что она экспортирует?

Comment: Предлагаю вам IntPtr и обозначить:) Если вас не интерисуют потроха FILE то так вполне логично будет. В противном случае вам прийдётся обьявить FILE и как-то ссылаться на него.

Comment: Приведите вашу dll-ку и функцию с которой у вас проблема. Одну мы вам покажем как проимпортировать:) (если dll не такая что через нет справку на неё не достанешь)

Comment: @nick_n_a потроха `FILE` вообще не стандартизированы, кстати, т.е. лезть туда надобности обычно никакой нет.

Comment: @alexout это не важно стандартизированы ли, конкретная ф-ция привязана к конкретной библиотеке, если к примеру используется msvcrt.dll то для неё FILE будет всегда конкретное (90% что её импортируют). А то что в неё не надо лезть - думаю что библиотека NET настолькобогата функциями работы с файлами, что доп библиотеки не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо вам всем, использовал IntPtr. Пока что не знаю, что в итоге получится, но попробую

Comment: Я вполне могу понять, зачем передавать из одной программы в другую имя файла. Или сохранять такое имя между запусками одной и той же программы. Но передавать указатель на структуру FILE... Это к чему ?! Ведь очевидно, что в другой программе, или при повторном запуске той же самой программы, эта структура уже не будет иметь никакого смысла! Простейший пример - запускаем одну и ту же программу два раза - один раз так, что её stdin назначен на консоль, а другой раз - так, что stdin назначен на текстовый файл... И какой смысл передавать указатель на структуру, описывающую stdin ?!